# How to Select values from column which has array data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

```html
    +--------------------+--------------------+
|              _VALUE|             paraarr|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Archer, Edward Pa...|[, [[, Arbitrator...|
|Archer, Edward Pa...|[, [[, Member:],,...|
|Archer, Edward Pa...|[, [[, Experience...|
|Archer, Edward Pa...|[, [[, Publicatio...|
|Belcher, A. Lee (...|[, [[, Arbitrator...|
|Belcher, A. Lee (...|[, [[, Member:],,...|
|Belcher, A. Lee (...|[, [[, Experience...|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Arbitrator...|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Member:],,...|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Experience...|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Public Sec...|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Issue:],,,,]]|
|Bloodsworth, Davi...|[, [[, Industry:]...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Arbitrator...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Profession...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Arbitratio...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Permanent ...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Issues:],,...|
|Brent, Daniel F. ...|[, [[, Industries...|
|Chiesa, Mario (Mi...|[, [[, Arbitrator...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Using AWS glue sql context , i want to explore the paraar column and want to extract data from this column.
I am very new to AWS glue.I am not able to find how should i go about it.

I have executed below code to get this data column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
dyf1.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("x3")
df1=spark.sql("select p._VALUE,explode(para_array) as paraarr from x2")
```

Comment: whats the response for DF1? does it has any value?  Also the view name seem to be wrong...is the code really working?

Comment: you are creating a view by name x3, but have x2 in your select statement...? Is it a typo?